# Azure Kusto Query: Reorder barchart bars

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitor-workbooks

I am rendering a barchart in Azure AppInsight Workbook. the grid result looks like below.

[image]

it's corresponding bar chart looks like below.

[image]

See how "2021 Q4" bar(blue) renders before "2021 Q3" bar(orange). I tried sort,order and project-order to order the graphs by name of "yearQuarter" in table(pic 1) but it always renders "2021 Q4" bar first as Q4 has more read percentage than Q3. Any help to reorder these bars by "yearQuarter" is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of the Azure Portal's bar charts is to order bar chart data series largest to smallest bar, so this is also the default behavior in Workbooks.

If you want bars in a specific order, you'll need to change the workbooks "Visualization" chart type dropdown to "Bar chart (Categorical)" which tells workbooks to tell portal that the X axis is categorical values and more important than the y-axis numeric values.  Then the bars will be in whatever order the query returned the rows.

[image: selecting bar chart categorical visualization]